html5 video (MP4) does not start automatically
I have this React page where I want to add a video to it but autoplay is not working I am using Opera GX but I tried also on Chrome and Edge and still the autoplay does not work on any of them:
import React from 'react';
import './home.css'; 
import video from '../../images/backgroundvid.mp4';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <video src={video} width="750" height="500"  autoplay muted loop>
      </video>
  );
};

export default Home;

When I add controls and play the video manually it works:
<video src={video} width="750" height="500" controls autoplay muted loop>


Your video tag doesn't have a source and a type... Maybe that is the problem?
I don't use React but generally (in HTML) the correct setup should look like:
import React from 'react';
import './home.css'; 
import video from '../../images/backgroundvid.mp4';

const Home = () => {
  return (
            <video width="750" height="500" muted autoplay loop>
            <source src={video} type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         );
};

export default Home;

